how to use sed on a grep matched string and display the complete output
here is what I'm trying to do..
I'm trying to cat a text file and display the full file and only changing some characters (which are appearing in other lines also), and use grep to match the key words from the selected line.
I am trying to do this all in one line command or commands, not by running a script.
For example, I have this text file, test_hasham.txt
cat test_hasham.txt

this is line one XXXXXX
this is line two XXXXXX
this is line three XXXXXX

I want to change "X" to "-" only on line which has word "two", the output should be all the lines in the original text file but only line with key word "two" changed.
this is line one XXXXXX
this is line two -----
this is line three XXXXXX

I'm trying something like this but it is changing all the "X" to "-"...how can I use grep and sed in one command to get the desires results.
this is what im doing but its changing all the X's to dashes, not only the line with the word two
cat test_hasham.txt |  (sed "s|X|-|g" ; grep two)
this is line one ------
this is line two ------
this is line three ------

In summary:
what i am getting:
cat test_hasham.txt |  (sed "s|X|-|g" ; grep two)
this is line one ------
this is line two ------
this is line three ------

what i want:
cat test_hasham.txt |  ( ****some magic sed + grep combo ****)
this is line one XXXXX
this is line two ------
this is line three XXXXX


If the number of spaces or the number of X is irrelevant, you should make this clear in the question, either in the description or by using examples with different numbers of characters. Also unclear: Is it guaranteed that the letter X does never occur in other places than the last field? (like this is XX line two XXXXXXXXXXX)

You never need sed+grep for anything. In fact piping sed/grep/awk to sed/grep/awk is an antipattern, see https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award#grep.
You should usually be using awk instead, e.g. using any awk:
$ awk '/two/{ gsub(/X/,"-") } 1' test_hasham.txt
this is line one XXXXXX
this is line two ------
this is line three XXXXXX

but in this case you can do it with just sed, e.g. using any POSIX sed (improved from my original version courtesy of feedback from @potong):
$ sed '/two/s/X/-/g' test_hasham.txt
this is line one XXXXXX
this is line two ------
this is line three XXXXXX


worked like a charm...i used the 2nd option of sed and thats exactly what i was looking for

In the sed solution since there is only one comand following the address/regex there is no need for the braces.

@potong thanks, I updated my answer. Do you know if that's true for all seds? I wanted to give it the best shot at being portable but wasn't sure if I could even leave off the ; or if non-GNU seds would require that.

From the posix specs it would seem that an address or range of address may be followed by a function. A function may be a single letter command or a list of commands beginning with { followed by single letter commands separated by newlines or ;'s and ending in }. Since { and } are treated as commands in some versions of sed the separator must follow the last command of a list i.e. {command1;command2;...;commandn;}.

@potong thanks, I updated my answer again given that info.

I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let test_hasham.txt content be
this is line one XXXXXX
this is line two XXXXXX
this is line three XXXXXX

then
awk 'BEGIN{FS="X";OFS="-"}/two/{$1=$1}{print}' test_hasham.txt

gives output
this is line one XXXXXX
this is line two ------
this is line three XXXXXX

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that X is field separator (FS) and - is output field separator (OFS), for lines containing two I trigger line rebuilt using $1=$1, others are left unchanged, all lines are printed. This solution will work with any character, including character of special meaning in regular expression e.g. field separator might be . (dot) which would cause gsub to replace all characters. You might elect to set FS and OFS via options if you plan to change them as follows
awk -v FS="X" -v OFS="-" '/two/{$1=$1}{print}' test_hasham.txt

(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)
